# How to rewrite delete and find command from Linux Shell to Window Command Prompt?

Tags: linux, shell, command-line, window, command-prompt

I have the following Shell command for Linux, I need to rewrite it for Window to be used in prompt Command Prompt.

```
find . -name \*.uncompressed.js -type f -delete and find . -name \*.js.map -type f -delete
```

At the moment I am using

```
del /s *.uncompressed.js and del /s *.js.map
```

but does not work.

Any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: You're not using the word 'and', are you?  You need two separate statements for Windows command line.

Comment: @Tony thanks for your comment, please add it as a answer I will accept it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need two separate statements for Windows command line.

```
del /s *.uncompressed.js
del /s *.js.map
```